# Why do people convert CRUD app into a REST API?

Tags: api, rest, crud

I'm a junior Rails developer and I'm trying to understand the pros/cons between CRUD web apps and REST API's.

I know how to turn a Rails Blog into an API, but I don't understand what advantages there are to doing this.

The main difference I can see is that my url for reading a blog went from this

`localhost:3000/blog/1`

to this

`localhost:3000/api/v1/blog/1`

And if I want to create a blog the url went from this

`localhost:3000/blog/new`

to this

`localhost:3000/api/v1/blog`

I made the view for the API and the Blog controller look exactly the same.
So the end result is that reading a blog or creating a blog has the exact same UX.

I feel like there is something I am not truly understanding about REST API's.

Can anyone describe a hypothetical situation where a Blog API would be better than a CRUD Blog?

Comment: Two totally different paradigms. You are speaking of only URLs. There are much more differences than just URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel like there is something I am not truly understanding about REST API's.

That's not your fault; there is a *lot* of misunderstanding about REST API's.  The Rails community in particular got confused circa 2005, and I don't know that it was ever straightened out.

```
localhost:3000/blog/1
localhost:3000/api/v1/blog/1
```

That's just a change of spelling convention.  REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your URI, but if you are using a framework (like Rails) to route HTTP requests to the appropriate implementation, then you want to choose spellings that make the routing easy ("convention over configuration").

```
localhost:3000/blog/new
localhost:3000/api/v1/blog
```

This change better aligns a "create" request with the caching semantics of the web.  It's often the case that adding a new entry to a blog also changes the blog resource itself (the new entry gets listed in the index, for example).  So after a successful create, you would like the client to stop using the old copy of the index and fetch a new one.

HTTP's cache invalidation rules describing invalidation of the target resource after a successful unsafe request, so this:

```
POST /api/v1/blog
```

instructs the client to invalidate its previously cached copies of /api/v1/blog (if the response isn't an error).  Which is great, because the /api/v1/blog representation has been changed by the addition of the new blog post.

```
POST /blog/new
```

has exactly the same semantics (because "uniform interface" -- all resources understand the same messages the same way).  Which means that a non error response informs general purpose clients that the /blog/new representation should be invalidated.

And that's probably *not* useful, because it's /blog, not /blog/new, that was changed when we added a new entry to the blog.

In general: the target-uri doesn't identify the handler of the action, it identifies the document (resources being generalizations of documents) that we are trying to change.  That allows us to leverage the caching magic that is built into the web.

Comment: "the target-uri doesn't identify the handler of the action, it identifies the document" -- this a fundamental misunderstanding by many developers!